# jQuery draggable out of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using `jQuery UI` for a personnal project and I want to know something. Is it possible to control the draggable jQuery item, in order to disable the possibility to get the `draggable` item out of the window ?

I'm not sure if I'm clear enough, so here is a screen of what I don't want to have : [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0zZu.jpg)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jQuery UI Draggable, you have an option called Containment. In that, you can specify the parent, inside which it should be constrained. In your case, the parent should be the body.

You can use this initiation function:

```
$( "#yourElement" ).draggable({ scroll: false });
```

You can also use the following:

```
$("#element").draggable({
    handle: tr_top,
    containment: "window"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I check the scroll function in the API Doc but I really don't understand how it works, and this is not working. For the second option, I also check the handle  functions, but with only the use of containment. And it's work. Just a question, is it possible to block the draggable item on the top/left/right but not at the bottom ?

Comment: Try this: 
The containment option allows an array where to set the positions whereto contain it. Try this:

`var containmentTop = $("#stop-top").position().top;
var containmentBottom = $("#stop-bottom").position().top;

$('#bar').draggable({axis: 'y', containment : [0,containmentTop,0,containmentBottom] });`

Comment: Thanks for this, but what is the #stop-top and #stop-bottom ?

Comment: Those are html elements either span or div having those ids you will be able to give an extremities to your drag motions where to stop at both ends.